# Nginx serving PHP file as download

Tags: linux, nginx, php, php-fpm, php7

I have a website with an index.php file (rhys.ddns.net/php/index.php). Whenever I try to access said file in my browser it is getting served as a download. I have checked my sites-enabled/default file and made changes suggested by others about exactly the same issue yet nothing is changing in behavior.

Server details:
Raspberry Pi B+ [ 
Nginx/1.14.1 : 
PHP7.2-FPM ]

Here are my config files (they are hosted separately as I am experiencing problems with the StackOverflow codeblocks)

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf - http://termbin.com/bz0nf

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default - http://termbin.com/y4fk

/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini - http://termbin.com/3jqj

/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf - http://termbin.com/wqm6

As always your help is appreciated and if U want me to post more files just comment :)

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/873286/nginx-trying-to-download-php-files ?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm just being dumb but I don't understand what exactly the first link is asking me to do.

Comment: I pasted some possible duplicate, but as I'am not a expert on nginx, I can't really mark it directly as duplicate, but please look around, it's a problem I seen asked much already on serverfault

Comment: Thankyou @yagmoth555 your 1st link worked. You can write it in the answers section and I will approve it.

Comment: I will tag it as a duplicate then :), thanks you for the feedback